# Questions repeat in Help and Improvement queue even after being marked low quality

Tags: bug, review-queues

I spent some time browsing the Help and Improvement queue today, making small edits to formatting and grammar where I could, and also flagging a whole bunch of questions as "very low quality". While I am pretty sure (but not 100% sure) that I did not see any of the questions that I edited reappear in front of me, I did have some of the flagged ones reappear two, three and even four times.

I am pretty sure that this behavior is not intentional (but of course correct me if I am wrong). It seems that once I have indicated my intent not to bother with a question multiple times, it should not keep coming back into my queue.

Comment: Flagging as VLQ sends it back to Triage, where they'll once again determine where it goes.  Given that they couldn't figure out how to handle it correctly the first time, it's not too surprising that they got it wrong the second (and third and fourth and fifth) time as well.

Comment: Interesting, I thought vlq notified a moderator

Comment: Mods can also see the flag, and if a mod gets to it before Triage does, then they could potentially act on it.  If the triage bots manage to mark it as needing editing before a mod sees it, the flag will be resolved though.

Comment: You mean bots figuratively?

Comment: Yes, I do mean it figuratively.

Comment: Would a mechanism that gave mods priority for items that had gone through such a cycle say three times be a good idea? Alternatively, direct access to close votes instead of just vlq would be very convenient.

Comment: It should really just be the whole flag dialog, rather than just VLQ.  Of course the *actual* solution is to help make Triage actually direct questions to the right place (at least a non-trivial percentage of the time).  Even having a question go between the two 3 times is *really* bad.

Comment: Having been new to review process myself, I think I understand why "needs editing" causes the most confusion. A very real solution may be to rename "needs editing" to something that reflects "can be edited/tweaked meaningfully by someone other than the author". It should be made more clear that "needs editing by the author" is "unsalvageable".

Comment: Indeed.  This has been mentioned to SE hundreds of times, consistently, over the course of several years.  It has thus far demonstrated beyond beyond their capability to edit a few labels to make them accurate, rather than completely wrong and actively harmful.  I've given up hope that they'll have any shot at actually making Triage useful at this point, as, apparently, has SE.

Comment: But they did manage to swap around all the buttons at the top so they no longer match the other SE sites, so at least we have that :)

Comment: See the difference is that they were able to objectively prove that that change resulted in more people clicking on links for their paid products (jobs), regardless of the effect on the quality of the product.  Spending 5 minutes of developer time to correct a completely broken label won't result in more people paying for job ads.

Comment: Still happens. Really annoying. I reject X, and Y, edit two, three other questions, then "next" gives me X and Y. Again. Which I rejected 5 minutes ago. wtf.