# How Low Quality questions get to Help and Improvement queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

There are few [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346052/help-and-improvement-needs-improvement) about [low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345034/questions-repeat-in-help-and-improvement-queue-even-after-being-marked-low-quali) questions in Help and Improvement queue which I agree for example new [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/17093153) is pretty much un-salvageable which became duplicate later,

So I wanted to know how this questions get into this queue (and why)?

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: flagging as Requires Editing is moved straight to Help queue?

Comment: Yes. Here's Shog's [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png) for a better visualization. ("Should be improved" in the chart is [the same as](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302511/6214222) "Requires Editing")

Comment: So I'll be careful with flagging as `Requires Editing`